# How do i recover code? Git noob

Tags: git

How do I recover my code?

I did the following two commands:

```
git log -all -p
git reflog
```

I see my code is there.  However, I'm not sure how to recover them.

Here's what the reflog shows:

```
23f50a6 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from filling-in-layout to master
39bdf8c HEAD@{1}: commit: Finished layout and routes
2ca279b HEAD@{2}: commit: Removed default Rails page
23f50a6 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to filling-in-layout
23f50a6 HEAD@{4}: merge static-pages: Fast-forward
436aabd HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from static-pages to master
23f50a6 HEAD@{6}: commit: Done with static pages
c11e8b0 HEAD@{7}: commit: Added a Pages controller
436aabd HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to static-pages
436aabd HEAD@{9}: commit: Improved the README and .Gitignore
a1d135d HEAD@{10}: commit (initial): Initial commit v.3
```

After I did the checkout as shown in `HEAD@{0}`, all my code was deleted and reverted back to `HEAD@{9}` status.  I'm such a noob at this, and I'm learning RoR with Hartl's Tutorial.  But, following his advice, all the work I've done in the past 5 hours is gone.  They should be in the `HEAD@{1}` commit.  Ahh..i have no clue what I'm talking about.  Please help :/

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: try `git reset --hard`, it will return you to the latest commit back.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should be really careful when you suggest or are suggested to use `git reset --hard` -- it is one of the few git commands which can cause an irrevocable loss of data. That said, in your situation it was probably safe.

If you did not any strange things to your repository, there is nothing to recover from; all your work sits safely on a branch; `git merge filling-in-layout` should solve your issue. Assuming you did create the branches just before switching to them, your repository looks as follows at the moment:

```
         static-pages
            master      filling-in-layout
o------o------X------o------o
```

where `X` designates the current commit. To get the changes in filling-in-layout, you just merge them to master.

As this is a fast-forward merge (i.e., the branches have not diverged), `git reset --hard` will do the same in this situation, except that it also irrevocably *removes all uncommited changes*. Also, if you were in a situation where filling-in-layout and master had diverged, e.g.

```
            master
o------o------X
 \
  \  filling-in-layout
   o------o
```

`git reset --hard filling-in-layout` would have you made losing (revocably) the commits which were in master and not in filling-in-layout.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the visual!  I appreciate your explanation, cebewee!

Comment: @PhilosophyNut: `git reset --hard` without arguments will not cause you to lose commits at all. It just returns your work tree and index to the state given by *the current commit*. It's `git reset --hard <commit>` that will potentially throw away commits - though they'll of course still be there, and you can get back to them using the reflogs.

Comment: @Jefromi: `git reset --hard` can cause irrevocable loss of data, since local changes that were not commited are discarded.

Comment: @Gauthier: I understand that, but I thought that the answer was slightly unclear that there was certain data which *wouldn't* be lost.

Answer (score 4):

You would do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't look like good advice. There could be (and appear to be) commits on `master` (`HEAD`) which aren't on `filling-in-layout` (`HEAD@{1}`), and this will throw them away!

Answer (score 1):

You have three branches: master, filling-in-layout, and static-pages.
The files on your disc reflect which commit you have checked out.

When you checked out master, the files on the disc were made to match the files commited in master.

If you want to revert to the state of the files in the branch filling-in-layout, just check out the branch:

```
git checkout filling-in-layout
```

If you want to take the changes you made in filling-in-layout, and import them to your master branch, merge as you did for HEAD@{4}:

```
git checkout master
git merge filling-in-layout
```

Note that if you already are on master and have local changes to you files on disc, you want to either commit the changes, discard them, or stash them before the merge.